# Show Progress bar with smtpClient.send

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am using this function to send mails via gmail.

```
private bool uploadToGmail(string username, string password , string file , 
    string backupnumber)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("jain@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("jain@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Backup mail- Dated- " + DateTime.Now + " part - " + 
        backupnumber;
    mail.Body = "Hi self. This mail contains \n backup number- " + 
        backupnumber + " \n Dated- " + DateTime.Now ;

    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(file);
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = 
        new System.Net.NetworkCredential("jain@gmail.com", "password");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

    SmtpServer.Timeout = 999999999;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    //  MessageBox.Show("mail Sent");
    return true;
}
```

Now I want to show a progress bar (in case there is a large attachment) to show the upload . Is this possible ? I think I know how to use a progress bar, but don't know how to use it with Smtpclient.send() .

any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [SendAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx) and subscribe to [SendCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted.aspx), to know, when the sending your mail completed. There is no way to get the progress of the send process, though...

Comment: Besides that, having an indication of the progress for one single mail would be pretty useless, because sending the data to the mail server would be just a fraction of the total time. The rest of the time is spent waiting for the server to respond to the request and waiting for the server to respond after sending the mail.

Comment: It depends. I think with big attachments, it will take most of the time to submit the mail to the server.