# I have a error on progress bar when sending email

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I would like to have a progress bar when sending the auto generated email but I'm getting errors. Please help me fix this. Any type of response is greatly appreciated.

I don't know if I'm on the right path, I'm a beginner on C# and just relying guides online so.

This line has the error

`new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(btnSend_Click));`

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        try
        {
            MailMessage loginInfo = new MailMessage();
            string em = "angelicasarimo15@gmail.com";
            loginInfo.To.Add(em.ToString());
            loginInfo.From = new MailAddress("vicserna1997@gmail.com");
            loginInfo.Subject = "Requesting Supplies";

            loginInfo.Body = "We want another supplies for blah blah blah" + System.Environment.NewLine +
            "This is a system generated email.";
            loginInfo.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("vicserna1997@gmail.com", "*Pass*");
            smtp.Send(loginInfo);
            MessageBox.Show("Email has been sent!", "Sent", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            System.Threading.Thread thread =
              new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(btnSend_Click));
            thread.Start();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Message not sent please check you internet connection", "Not Sent", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: You might want to remove the `try/catch`, or at least modify the `catch` to only catch specific exceptions that you know how to deal with

Comment: It looks like you are starting a thread that starts the same method over and over again...that looks like an endless loop.

Comment: BTW which technology? Windows Forms? It might help readers if you specify that in text and/or with tags.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SendAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091438/show-progress-bar-with-smtpclient-send) and subscribe to [SendCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted.aspx). This will notify you the sending process is completed. I don't believe its possible to get the progress of the sending email.